# Creating Dynamic attributes for Mongo Collection - YII Framework

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am trying to create dynamic model class for Mongo Collection and populate data in Cgridview (using YIIMongodbsuite extension)

Getting Column from MySQL DB:

```
$sql="SELECT name FROM CRM_Field Where crm_base_contact_id = ".$base;
$names =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->query()-> readAll();
```

Accessing Model in view:

```
 $cc = new ContactCollection($names);// Passing dynamic column names to Model 
 $criteria = new EMongoCriteria;
 $criteria->crm_base_contact_id('==', $base);
 $cc->setDbCriteria($criteria);
```

CgridView Code:

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' =>'BCImported-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $cc->search(false),
    'columns' => $names,
        )); ?>
```

ContactCollection Model :

```
<?php
class ContactCollection extends EMongoDocument
    {
        public $dyn_fields;
   public function __construct ($names) {
        $this->dyn_fields = $names;

    }

  public function getCollectionName()
      {
        return 'cartoons';
      }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $allMembers = implode(', ', array_keys($this->dyn_fields));
        return array(
            array($allMembers, 'required'),
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
       return $this->dyn_fields;
    }
    }
```

I am getting this error `" Property "ContactCollection.0" is not defined."`

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Also, if you are using YIIMongodbsuite, look at the EMongoSoftDocument, it does exactly what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "attributeLabels()" method in that case since each attribute should have an associated value. If you don't set that method, Yii will use the property name as the label itself.